# Is there a way to convert a std::stack<pointer> to std::stack<const pointer>?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, stack

Here is some background. I have a binary tree iterator (say in-order). It is keeping track of its current node's parent nodes by pushing the pointers on top of a stack. Now I also want *interoperability*, i.e. the ability to cast `iterator` to `const_iterator`. But `iterator` has `std::stack<pointer>` and `const_iterator` has `std::stack<const pointer>`.

Any other way of achieving the same effect is also appreciated.

## EDIT

Currently I have discarded the idea of using `std::stack` entirely. I am using `std::deque` and `push_back()` + `pop_back()` + `back()`. For converting `std::deque<pointer>` to `std::deque<const pointer>`, I am just using `std::copy( std::begin(ptrDeque), std::end(ptrDeque), std::begin(constPtrDeque) );` and this setup ***simply works***.

I would still like answers to this question out of curiosity.

Comment: You can also use `std::transform` if the transformation is bit more complicated. In this case, `std::copy` is fine.

Comment: Instead of `std::copy`, you should use the [range form of insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/insert) on deque; it can be much faster in some CRT implementations. As for using `deque` instead of `stack` -- by default, they are the same underlying data structure. `std::stack<t>` is just an adapter that provides stack semantics to some other container; which is often deque by default. (I think it may also be vector, but I don't recall exactly)

Comment: @BillyONeal It is `deque` AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

Just keep a non-const stack in your const_iterator. It's a private data member, so it doesn't really matter.

Make sure your const_iterator implementation doesn't modify through the pointers. To be double sure, always use your const_iterator's own operator*() which should return a const reference. (Actually, I don't think you need to dereference the pointer much, but in case you do, that's how. you should do it.)

Comment: I know this is a possible solution, but having a _non-const pointer_ in a _const iterator_ bugs me.

Comment: @Hindol: That doesn't make any sense. The constness of the iterator refers to the constness of what it contains: the pointer. But the pointer itself can be const or non const; it is completely unrelated to whether or not you had a const_iterator pointing to it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do these kind of transformations in C++. It looks like a cast would be sufficient, but it doesn't work this way.

The C++-way is to hide the crucial data-structures and manage access by different APIs.
Yes, that means at one point you have less `const` than desired. But that's what hiding is for.
As long as it's only in the implementation no one else can misuse it.

You can get quite close to the desired solution if you encapsulate your stack/deque/whatever [I guess `vector` would be suffient] in a dedicated class. Internally it keeps non-const pointers, but all `const` methods return `const pointer`s. If your iterators access it only through getters, it should be impossible to bypass the `const` accidently.

Comment: The setup is a bit more complicated as I am using `boost::iterator_facade`. As soon as I use `Iterator<const Node>`, constness is propagated to many other types (`node_pointer` is one of them). Trying to avoid `const pointer` altogether is a lot more work than using `std::deque`.

Comment: I haven't used `iterator_facade` so far. Looking at the docs I'm not sure if it's worth the effort. Especially not if the iterator contains more than just a pointer. Copying seems unavoidable. I wrote some stuff with iterators, which might be similar to yours (vectors as cache). There `Iterator` is derived from `ConstIterator` so interoperability comes at no cost. Of course `ConstIterator` contains non-const pointers into the datastructure, but since all methods in question are const themselves there is almost no risk of a mixup.